# Determinar aquellos dígitos que están en el primer número, pero no en el segundo

Tags: python

Codificar un algoritmo que reciba dos números enteros positivos y retorne otro número que corresponde a aquellos dígitos que están en el primer número, pero no en el segundo. En caso que no exista diferencia debe retornar 0.

Ejemplo:
determinarDiferencia(6328, 6817)
Salida esperada: 32

Intenté con este código, sin embargo no llego bien a la solución ¿alguna mejor idea?

```
    pNum = 6328
    pNum2 = 6817
    potencia = 0
    ultimoDigito = 0
    ultimoDigito2 = 0
    resultado = 0

while(pNum != 0):
    ultimoDigito = pNum % 10
    ultimoDigito2 = pNum2 % 10

    while(ultimoDigito != ultimoDigito2):
        pNum2 = pNum2 // 10
        ultimoDigito2 = pNum2 % 10
    pNum = pNum // 10
    resultado = (ultimoDigito *(10**potencia)) + resultado
    potencia+=1

print("El nuevo valor es: " + repr(resultado))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes conseguirlo haciendo uso de [conjuntos](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets), además de ciertos [type castings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion).

Al usar conjuntos, puedes realizar la operación de [diferencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferencia_de_conjuntos) entre ellos, para saber qué dígitos están en el primer número y no en el segundo.

Por supuesto, previamente es necesario convertir los números de entrada, a algún tipo de iterable (que sea hasheable), antes de poder considerar usar conjuntos para solucionar este problema. El mejor candidato entre los iterables que tenemos para este fin, son las strings.

Así, ya teniendo los dígitos que buscamos, podemos volver a tener un número entero (el de salida), encadenando los elementos del conjunto resultante de la diferencia de conjuntos, en una string, valiéndonos del método `join()` de la clase `str`.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
def make_new_number(number_a, number_b):
    numbers = set(str(number_a)) - set(str(number_b))
    return int(''.join(numbers) or '0')
```

El cual se puede usar así:

```
>>> make_new_number(6328, 6817)
32
>>> make_new_number(6871, 6817)
0
```

Comment: El problema es que en un conjunto no se garantiza el orden. `make_new_number(6328, 6817)` en realidad da `23`, no `32`. Un modo más directo que garantiza el orden: `''.join(c for c in str(number_a) if c not in str(number_b))`.

Comment: Me salvaron la vida compañeros, muchas gracias.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Sí, tienes razón. Es algo que debí tomar en cuenta. En la sesión que tenía abierta en mi REPL, obtuve `32` y eso me hizo ignorar el hecho que bien apuntas. Mi reflejo mental de asociar esta situación con una diferencia de conjuntos, fue más veloz que la reflexión necesaria para tomar eso en cuenta. Eliminaré mi respuesta y te invito a que coloques la tuya que, considero, aborda mejor esta situación.